# Why am I Getting System.Threading.ThreadAbortException when setting a 404 response code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

I have the following code in my app.

if _showConfiguration is null and the Response object is NOT null, then the status code is set to 404, and response ends.

That is how the previous developer wrote this. Now, when we create a new page that contains the ShowConfiguration object, it is always throwing System.Threading.ThreadAbortException.

I would like to know what is causing it. Please advise.

Thanks

```
public ShowConfiguration ShowConfig
{
    get
    {
        if (_showConfiguration == null)
        {
            _showConfiguration = ShowConfigurationCache.GetShowByAliasPath(_aliasPath);


            if (_showConfiguration == null && Response != null)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.StatusCode = 404;
                Response.End();
            }


        }

        return _showConfiguration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is the nature of Response in ASP.NET. Even doing a Response.Redirect results in a ThreadAbortException because it is finished processing the current request. To avoid it, pass the 2nd parameter as false which will avoid this. see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312629.

of course, it depends on your intentions here but by default, this is the behaviour in ASP.NET.

this may also give you a bit of a background on Response.End:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx

summary is that the Response.End method ends the current page execution and moves its execution to the Application_EndRequest event in the application's event pipeline. Any line of code after Response.End is not executed, but will throw the exception.

you should be doing HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest. But again, the behaviour you are seeing is normal and expected

Comment: I would add that doing a redirect means returning current thread to the thread pool and taking another with for the request following redirection.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Hi, but I am not doing a redirect in my code though...I am only calling Response.Clear(), then Response.StatusCode=404, then Response.End(). Could you explain? Thanks

Comment: @doglin Yes but you are doing `Response.End ()` what basically means that current thread is no longer available.

Comment: Right and that's what I said as well as saying the same thing happens with Response.Redirect. In general, you can safely ignore the exception. it does not get relayed back to the client or stop the processing of your website flow/logic.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas   Got it...thnx for explanation. All clear!!